# understanding double buffers

Tags: double, buffer, hid

I am using the C8051F320 and basing my firmware on the HID example firmware (for example, BlinkyExample).

IN and OUT reports are each 64B long (a single 64B packet).

I enabled the ADC and set it for 10kSps. Every ADC interrupt, a sample is stored in an array. When enough samples are taken to fill a packet, an IN packet is sent.

Software sends a report telling the firmware how many reports to return.

1) The example firmware uses EP1, which has 128B. It splits the EP into IN and OUT, 64B each.

The firmware drops the first sample of each IN report at 10kSps. At 5kSps it runs fine.

2) I modified EP1 to be double buffered, but it is only 32B long now. Regardless, streaming 1000s of IN reports with 10kSps data works great (confirmed by FFT of the sampled sine wave in software).

3) I modified the firmware to use EP2, since that has 256B total, giving 64B if splitting and double buffering.

a) Again, at 10kSps, the first sample of each packet is dropped. Why? It runs fine at 5kSps.

Actually, I cannot seem to visualize how double buffering works. If the sample rate is faster than the HID transfer rate, the FIFOs will overflow regardless, right? How does double buffering help? But it seems that for double-buffering to be effective, the packet size must be cut in half.

b) While switching references of EP1 to EP2, I came across this code in F3xx_USB0_Standard_Requests.c: DATAPTR = (unsigned char*)&ONES_PACKET;. Setting a char* = address of a char* does not seem correct to me. I modified it to DATAPTR = (unsigned char*)ONES_PACKET; Regardless, there seems to be no difference. What does the zeros and ones arrays do?

Answer (score 0):

> HID example firmware

HID uses interrupt type endpints, which will transfer data *at most* once per frame, or once per 1 ms - depending on your HID descriptor, it can be much slower. This yields a net data rate of about 64000 Bytes/sec.

Once you need to transfer more data, use bulk or isochronous endpoints.